# The solutions of second-order ODE $y''+ay=0$ with a negative coefficient are hyperbolic functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a partial differential equation where

$$u(a,\theta,z)=0,\quad -\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi, \quad 0\leq z \leq b$$
$$u(r,\theta,b)=0,\quad 0 \leq r < a,\quad -\pi\leq \theta \leq \pi$$
$$u(r,\theta,0)=f(r,\theta),\quad 0 \leq r < a ,\quad -\pi\leq \theta \leq \pi$$

I stop in this differential equation: $$ Z''(z)+\lambda Z(z)=0$$

I have to prove that when $$ \lambda=-\beta^2$$ then $$ Z(z)=C\sinh[\beta(b-z)]$$ but I do not have idea how to prove it; someone could help?

---

Edit: I am trying to solve this problem:

$$ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial \theta^2}+\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial z^2}=0$$ where if $$u(r,\theta,z)=R(z)T(\theta)Z(z)$$ when $\frac{Z''(z)}{Z(z)}=-\lambda$ and $\lambda=-\beta^2$

Comment: Key terms: characteristic equation, exponential functions.

Comment: @sally Thanks sally, I did it but the problem is that I get that $C=\frac{f(r,\theta)}{\sin{\beta b}}$ so $C$ is not const. My problem says that $C$ is const. more help? thanks

Comment: Well, you haven't even said what PDE you are trying to solve, only listed the boundary conditions. The method of separation of variables requires homogeneous boundary conditions. Nonhomogeneous conditions can  _sometimes_ be dealt with by subtracting a function from $u$.

Comment: I edit it is true I do not give all notes sorry

Comment: If $\lambda=-\beta^2$, a basis of solutions is $\{e^{\beta z},e^{-\beta z}\}$. Note that the solution you were given, $C\sinh(\beta(b-z))$, is a linear combination of these hence we are in textbook territory, really.